# React: Is it possible to stop code 'reading' until component will receive new props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component, that has button that creates `newType` on click and sets it to state. 
`types` comes from outside from parent component. How can I stop running the code at the moment when `this.props.onCreateClick(this.state.selectedDate)` runs and wait until I receive updated `types` so when I get updated `types` I could run next line?

It's class component. That button is inside 
Props example: `props: types = [{id: 1, name: 'One'}, {id: 2, name: 'Two'}]`

```
this.state = {
   selectedDates: [Date], 
   currentType: null, 
}

<button
    onClick={(e) => {
        this.props.onCreateClick(this.state.selectedDate)
        let newType = this.props.types[this.props.types.length - 1]; 

        this.setState({
            selectedDates: [], 
            currentType: newType.id
        })
    }}

>Create</button>
```

Comment: you can control it using `componentDidUpdate()` and compare types coming from props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
this.state = {
   selectedDates: [Date], 
   currentType: null, 
}

<button
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.onCreateClick(this.state.selectedDate).then(types => {
            let newType = types[types.length - 1]; 

            this.setState({
                selectedDates: [], 
                currentType: newType.id
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            //handle error
        });

    }}

>Create</button>
```

And `onCreateClick` function return Promise which `reslove` new types you recieve and then you process them in state of you component.

If you wish you could change this code to `async\await`, same work with promises.

Answer (score 0):

I'd return something like a boolean from `onCreateClick()` and store that in a variable. Then you can easily check wether that variable is set or not.

```
this.state = {
   selectedDates: [Date], 
   currentType: null, 
}

handleOnClick = () => {
  const isHandled = this.props.onCreateClick(this.state.selectedDate)
  if(isHandled){
    let newType = this.props.types[this.props.types.length - 1]; 

    this.setState({
       selectedDates: [], 
       currentType: newType.id
    })
  }
}

<button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleOnClick()}>Create</button>
```

Comment: But here if server is slow at this time and it returns answer later than React executes code and reads the next line, will I get `undefined` in `isHandled ` const?

Comment: Depends on what code there is inside the `onCreateClick` function. Please provide more code if you want a in depth answer.